# Specific search in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, search

I need to search file names in a directory for position based characters. I am looking for files with parenthesis within parenthesis. 
like this:

```
# 2262281102-03_Cutting_Plate_Lower_Stop_(Anschlag_Cutting_Frame_(Schnittgestell)_unten)_400kN

GET-CHILDITEM C:\BU\p -recurse | WHERE-OBJECT {$_.nAME -MATCH "(?!)((?!)((!?))(!?))(!?)"}
```

I also need to match any file with 4+ letters and no parenthesis. ie:

```
# 2277131504-03_Haltebolzen_platte

GET-CHILDITEM C:\BU\p -EXCLUDE "*)*" -recurse | WHERE-OBJECT {$_.nAME -MATCH "\W\.[^\W]"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this:

```
$tests = @(
'2262281102-03_Cutting_Plate_Lower_Stop_(Anschlag_Cutting_Frame_(Schnittgestell)_unten)_400kN',
'2277131504-03_Haltebolzen_platte'
)


$regex = '^.*\(.*\(.*\).*\).*$|^[^()]*[a-z]{4}[^()]*$'

$tests -match $regex
2262281102-03_Cutting_Plate_Lower_Stop_(Anschlag_Cutting_Frame_(Schnittgestell)_unten)_400kN
2277131504-03_Haltebolzen_platte
```